# How to style deeper elements of Flowbite React Components

Tags: reactjs, flowbite

Like when I get a search bar component from Flowbite. Can I style just the input element inside that component? If that possible, how?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are using react flowbite, so in this case, for your search bar you need a TextInput, from [forms](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/forms#default-form)

And at the bottom you see the detail of the [theme](https://www.flowbite-react.com/docs/components/forms#theme) typing of TextInput and other element, you can add the detail of the them directly in this specific component by the prop "theme" or manage it in your global flowbite theme.

This section of theme will allow you to manipulate the appearance of the inner element from the textInput.